# Is there a way to disable sounds (such as "beeps") in my mac app?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I know I need to dig the reason why my app is beeping in the code, etc.

But I was wondering, is there a global setting to disable sounds all over my app screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very little information to go on, but usually your application is beeping when the responder chain comes up with no object that can respond to an event on the screen or keyboard. 
For instance, if you type text in an active view and the view doesn't allow for text editing, the view sends the key down event to its super view. For a view this can end by the NSPanel or NSWindow or BSWindow controller. The last responder in the chain invokes the noResponderFor: method, which, when not implemented, will give a beep. If you don't want it to beep, override this method to do something else.
Based on your information I can't give you any other information.